# how to handle this default parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which has two default parameters and one regular 
parameter.

```
var Fields = function ($content, result = failedObject, job = true) 
{
    ...
}
```

When I call `Fields($content,job)`, job here could be true or false, the result parameter takes in the job value rather than the third parameter. Works good in the case if `Fields($content,result)`.

Any good way to tackle this situation.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

you would call `Fields($content, undefined, job)` to use the default value for the parameter `result`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *destructured* argument :

```
var Fields = function ($content, { result = failedObject, job = true } = { }) {
    ...
}
```

Then, when you call the function :

```
const data = { result: anotherObject, job = false };
Fields('toto', data);
```

Or, in your specific case :

```
const data = { job = false };
Fields('toto', data); // result still is a failedObject
```

Comment: Downvoting, no comment ?

Comment: There is no need to change function signature. Just pass `undefined` as param value

Comment: What if OP can't change function signature?

Comment: @ponury-kostek I'm just suggesting a another possible solution, OP doesn't says he wants to keep the same signature

Comment: So why not to pass all parameters in single object?

Comment: Yes, this is another solution among many others

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your question correctly, javascript does not support named parameters natively, so you can call by `Fields($content, undefined, job)`

or using an object as parameter for your function instead of 3 params.

Answer (score 0):

Pass empty/undefined/null:

Fields($content, , job);

Comment: `Fields($content, , job)` is syntax error. Passing `null` will set param value to `null`. Only `undefined` is proper way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Passing_undefined_vs._other_falsy_values

Comment: yeah exactly only undefined would work .

Answer (score -1):

You must switch the order(like below), or using an array and treat inside function.

```
var Fields = function ($content, job = true, result = failedObject, ) 
     {
     }
```